# rhev manager external vm?

Tags: rhev

I test RHEV manager 3.3 and RHEV host 3.3
I installed vm(RHEL 6.5 x64) on RHEV host used by RHEV manager.
And RHEV manager crash and I can't fix it. So I reinstall RHEV manager and add RHEV host.
I can see vm, but can't configure vm and can't add exist storage domain.

RHEV manger error message.

Error while executing action:

external-vm-54
   Cannot edit VM. This VM is not managed by the engine.

Thank you.

Comment: What's  RHEV?!?!

Comment: @ewwhite seriously?

Comment: @ewwhite RedHat Enterprise Virtualization

Answer (score 1):

This is probably the worst formulated question on this site. But I will provide an answer anyhow.

- If you are installing an all-in-one system, there RHEV-Manager and a managed host are both running on the same machine, there are step by step guides provided, which you should follow. They are exhaustively simple and detailed and should answer any question you might have.
- If you are trying to use the self hosted engine feature, again, there is a guide and specific action flows you need to follow, and things will simply work.
- In any case, since this is RHEV you are talking about, you should be able to contact RHT support and ask them to look into whatever issue you might be having.